# Usar entity framework con Base de datos existente

Tags: c#, entity-framework

estoy intentando aprender a manejar Entity Framework y en todos los tutoriales/manuales que he seguido, siempre parten de la creación y mapeo de la base de datos a manejar.
Pero que pasa si diseño una aplicación para trabajar en una base de datos que ya estará creada en la máquina de destino.
Trabajando con ADO.Net, no hay problema, ya que es la cadena de conexión la que se encargará ello y la puedo generar en tiempo de ejecución,
¿Pero como puedo hacerlo en Entity Framework si tengo que generar el modelo de datos en tiempo de diseño?

Comment: Entity Framework ofrece 2 flujos de trabajo, `Model First`, que creo es al que haces referencia al principio y el otro es `Database First` que me parece es el que buscas. [Este enlace](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx) y [este otro](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first) pueden ser útiles.

Comment: 5 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes, 2. Dale una visita al tour: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Esto te ayudará a entender mejor el sitio y cómo participar a buen ritmo 3. Mira cómo realizar preguntas en https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 4. Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 5. ¿Versión de EF? o ¿Estás con EF Core?

Comment: Gracias @fredyfx así lo haré.
En cuanto a la versión, estoy usando EF Core, aunque lo estoy usando en un proyecto de .Net Framework, pero así es como lo indican en el curso que estoy siguiendo.

Answer (score 0):

Has intentado el siguiente comando en el package console en visual studio?

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myserver;Database=mydatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Este comando deberia crear tu dbcontext y las entidades.

Para ver el ejemplo completo mira el siguiente link: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6116/create-entity-data-model-using-a-database-first-approach/